# Distinct eigenvalues in a 3×3 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Suppose that $A$ is a $3\times3$ real matrix with $k$ **distinct** real eigenvalues and $l$ **distinct** complex (i.e., non-real) eigenvalues. Consider the following statements:
>
> (i) $k=2,l=0$
>   (ii) $k=0,l=3$
>   (iii) $k=1,l=2$
>   (iv) $k=2,l=1$
>
> How many of the above statements are possible?
>
> (A) None; (B) $1$; (C) $2$; (D) $3$; (E) All of them.

I have been trying to solve this question, I know statement iii) is true since complex eigenvalues come in pairs, but I can't figure out what other statement is true since the Eigenvalues must be distinct. Anybody have any idea?

The answer is C) 2.

Comment: i) is also possible.

Comment: Consider the characteristic polynomial of said matrix. We know that it would be of degree 3. What kind of roots can you have of a degree 3 polynomial?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thats what I was thinking but since the eigenvalues must be distinct and and n by n matrix always has n eigenvalues wouldn't that mean one of the eigenvalues has a multiplicity of 2, and therefore its not distinct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right in saying that option iii) must be true. In addition as Omnomnomnom has pointed out, i) is also true, because, there can be repeated real eigenvalues, thus giving us only two **distinct** eigenvalues in total.

Comment: Oh, okay. That makes sense now, I was just confused on what they meant by distinct.